# Class that accepts iterator as argument, and stores values?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator

Suppose I want to implement a class that iterates over some range, and stores those values in an array at random indices. So I want something where I can write:

```
string s = "Steve";
auto r1 = RandomArray<char>(s.begin(), s.end());
int a[] = {1,2,3};
auto r2 = RandomArray<int>(begin(a), end(a));
// Later on...
for (const auto ch: r1) {/* do something */}
```

How would I define such a class? I can't figure out what the templating should look like. That is, how do I fill in what's missing below?

```
// template stuff
class RandomArray {
    public:
    RandomArray(/* some iterator argument(s) */) {
        // Pretend arr_ has already been sized correctly.
        for (const auto it = /* iterate over iterator */) {
            arr_[randomIndex()] = it;
        }
    }
    private:
    /* Some type */ arr_[];
};
```

I'm ignoring all the other things I'd eventually need (move constructors, begin/end, etc.).  I just want to figure out what the template statement before the class should look like.

Comment: What you are really looking for are user-specified template deduction guides, that were introduced in C++17.

Comment: Do you expect the type of `arr_` to somehow magically depend on which `RandomArray` constructor was called at runtime? That ain't gonna fly. You could make `RandomArray` a class template parameterized on the element type, and then a function template like `MakeRandomArray` would manufacture the correct specialization based on its arguments. Similar to `std::make_pair`. Or, it's possible I thoroughly misunderstood the nature of the problem; a more complete explanation of the ultimate goal of the exercise might help.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I'd like the type of arr_ to correspond to the value type of the iterator. I just don't know how to express that. The purpose of the "even better" constructors is to simply emphasize I don't want to pass begin/end, but rather the iterable itself. You can regard it as secondary to the main question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I am fine with having a separate functions to make the instance. I just don't know what the template of that function would look like

Comment: You have `RandomArray<string>(s.begin(), s.end())` taking iterators whose value is `char` (not `string`). And then you have `RandomArray<int>` taking iterators whose value is, in fact, `int`. What's the supposed role of `RandomIterator`s template parameter? Is it the type of the element, the type of some container, something else?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: yes, your'e right, that should be `char`. I would like the template parameter to be the value type of the iterator (and thus the type of arr_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines (untested):

```
template <typename Elem>
class RandomArray {
public:
  template <typename InputIter>
  RandomArray(InputIter first, InputIter last)
    : storage(first, last) {}

  template <typename Container>
  explicit RandomArray(const Container& c)
    : storage(std::cbegin(c), std::cend(c)) {}

  // For C-style array
  template <typename Elem2, size_t N>
  explicit RandomArray(Elem2 (&arr)[N])
    : storage(std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr)) {}

private:
  std:vector<Elem> storage;
};

template <typename InputIter>
auto MakeRandomArray(InputIter first, InputIter last) {
  return RandomArray<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type>(
    first, last);
}

template <typename Container>
auto MakeRandomArray(const Container& c) {
  return RandomArray<typename Container::value_type>(c);
}

// For C-style array
template <typename Elem, size_t N>
auto MakeRandomArray(Elem (&arr)[N]) {
  return RandomArray<Elem>(arr);
}
```